# Access data from a BIRT dataset within a Java class

Tags: java, eclipse, dataset, birt

I am relatively new with BIRT eclipse. I created a java project and a report file. The report has an Oracle DB connection, and I am working with one table. I want to access BIRT datasets with Java, so I can manipulate data rather than using only JavaScript. I have an idea in which I could connect them through importing the Java class to the `onFetch()` method on the dataset, but I'm unsure.

Comment: Please extend your question an describe what you want to achieve. This looks like a XY-Problem: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/190805

Comment: I would like to somehow how, within a eclipse birt report, load data from a dataset (pulled by a query) to a java class. So I can manipulate data.

Comment: The manipulation is needed in the report. I have an idea of loading data from a query into arrays and performing different calculations, and then send that data back to the report design. I would like to use Java only because that is my comfort zone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want to use are "computed columns". For a data set you can add computed columns additional to the fetched columns from your data source. In the computation script you can reuse the fetched columns as input for your computation. As a result your data set contains your fetched columns and your computed columns.

This example adds 1 to the fetched value of the column PK:

[image]